# How can I convert an existing jHipster project to mobile app?

Tags: spring, jhipster

I have an existing jhipster project, I have also created some custom components on front end.

I want to convert this project into mobile app using ionic.

I am using

`yo jhipster-ionic`

command to create ionic app but I am getting a fresh project

Are there any steps which I should follow?

Comment: You can't convert a JHipster project automatically. That is, there's no migration tools to do it for you. You can generate screens for your existing entities though. Just run `ionic4j entity <name>` and it should work.